# How does Box<dyn Trait> deconstruct itself?

Tags: rust

Since it doesn't know the concrete type of the data, it only contains a vtpr of dyn Trait, How does it drop itself when it goes out of scope? Does every virtual table in Rust contains a drop method implementation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When the concrete type the original `Box` contained is unsized into a trait object, the `Drop` implementation for the type goes into the vtable. A pointer (Any pointer-like thing in Rust. IE, a reference, `Box`, raw pointer, etc.) whose pointee is a trait object is laid out as follows in memory*:

```
struct FooTraitDynPointer {
    ptr: *[const/mut] (),
    vtable: &'static VTableImplForFooTrait
}
```

The `ptr` field in my example points to the actual data. We could say that's the original `Box`.

The `vtable` field in my example points to a static vtable. Say we have the following `Foo` trait:

```
trait Foo {
    fn bar(&self) -> usize;
}
```

Our vtable will look as follows*:

```
struct VTableImplForFooTrait {
    dropper: unsafe fn(*mut ()),
    size: usize,
    align: usize,
    bar: unsafe fn(*const ()) -> usize,
}
```

We see there, that the `drop` *is* there. Along with it, there're size and align fields which allow owning types to deallocate enough memory. Or re-allocate enough memory.

Here's an example program which crudely extracts the size of a struct from within a pointer to a trait object:

```
#![feature(raw)]

trait Foo {
    fn bar(&self) -> usize;
}

struct Baz {
    field: f64
}

impl Foo for Baz {
    fn bar(&self) -> usize {
        self.field as usize
    }
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct FooVTable {
    dropper: unsafe fn(*mut ()),
    size: usize,
    align: usize,
    bar: unsafe fn(*const ()) -> usize,
}

fn main() {
    use std::{mem, raw};
    let value = Baz { field: 20.0 };

    let boxed = Box::new(value) as Box<dyn Foo>;

    let deconstructed: raw::TraitObject = unsafe { mem::transmute(boxed) };

    let vtable = deconstructed.vtable as *mut FooVTable;

    let vtable = unsafe { (*vtable).clone() };

    println!("size: {}, align: {}", vtable.size, vtable.align);

    let result = unsafe { (vtable.bar)(deconstructed.data) };

    println!("Value: {}", result);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8a71cf230d5ab72912090a26454ef9ea)

(Currently) prints:

```
size: 8, align: 8
Value: 20
```

However this may very well change in the future so I'm leaving this timestamp here for someone who reads this in a future where the behaviour has been changed. June 5, 2020.

---

*: The layout of trait objects, and especially their vtables is **NOT** guaranteed, so do not rely in actual code.